# jQuery scrollTop() position to percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

```
<script>
document.getElementById('listen-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('music-player').play();
});
```

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 1400)
        document.querySelector('#music-player').pause();
    });
</script>
```

The button starts the audio player and scrolls to the section where the audio player is visible. When you scroll the the next section the audio player stops once you've scrolled 1400 but I need that to be relative. How to I make the 1400 a percentage (50%)

Comment: What do you need it relative to? The page height?

Comment: Yes the page height, I think. If the page height is 100% would scrolling half way down the page be 50% or would I need to convert the page height to pixels? Basically once the scroll bar is 66% scrolled down the audio needs to stop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is possible — some arithmetic will do the job. The trick is to retrieve the page height using `$(document).height()`. If you're referring to the viewport height though, then you will need to use `$(window).height()`.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height()*0.5)
    document.querySelector('#music-player').pause();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this code:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   var wh = $(document).height();

// st : wh = X : 100
// x = (st*100)/wh

var perc = (st*100)/wh

// Your percentage is contained in perc variable

console.log('The percentage is '+perc);

});
```

Comment: Just a side note: if you want to have 100% if you reached the bottom, use this line: `var wh = $(document).height() - $(window).height();` instead.